# How can I get protected values of an object of eway response?

Tags: php, sdk, eway

When I try to get Customer info by TokenCustomerID in my eway sdk.It return a object .Please find object screenshot.

I want to access data from this object, but how ?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't access protected properties directly.  Look at the class for the getter methods it offers.

Comment: May i use ReflectionProperty::getValue ?

Comment: I would think that would only be useful for the default value defined in the class not an instance's actual value.

Comment: this class call here
https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php/blob/master/src/Rapid/Model/Response/CreateCustomerResponse.php

Comment: And in this call https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php/blob/master/src/Rapid/Model/Customer.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eWAY PHP SDK uses traits to implement many features, including the get/set functionality - these can be found in [HasAttributesTrait](https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php/blob/master/src/Rapid/Model/Support/HasAttributesTrait.php)

This means you can access the properties directly even though they are labelled as protected when you dump the object:

```
$response = $client->queryCustomer(917758625852);
$tokenCustomerID = $response->Customers[0]->TokenCustomerID;
```